# How to generate .dll file with cmake?

Tags: windows, cmake

I am trying to generate `dll` file with the source file in cmake. It is giving configured done and generated done.But the `.dll` and `.lib` files are not generated. Please provide solution for this problem.

My cmake configuration in root is :

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(mydll C)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../common/include) 

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(mydll bin)

cmake configuration in mydll directory is :

SET(my_lib_src dllmain.cpp mydll.cpp funcs.def)

ADD_LIBRARY(mydll  SHARED ${my_lib_src})

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(mydll PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
```

Comment: Did you compile your project after the generation ?

Comment: No, I didn't compile the solution after the generation

Comment: That's the problem. Generate on CMake create the solution but does not compile it. When you will have compiled the solution you'll have your files.

Comment: Is there any options to set in CMakeLists.txt to compile with cmake and generate the dll ?

Comment: After compiling the solution i am getting error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __DllMainCRTStartup@12 ? Am i makde any mistake in CMakeLists.txt ?

Comment: I think it is another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will make it as a response, not in comment.

You problem here is that you are not compiling your solution, you are just generating it...

It seems that you can build your project with the command line :

```
cmake --build <dir> [options] [-- [native-options]]

    <dir>          = Project binary directory to be built.
    --target <tgt> = Build <tgt> instead of default targets.
    --config <cfg> = For multi-configuration tools, choose <cfg>.
    --clean-first  = Build target 'clean' first, then build.
                     (To clean only, use --target 'clean'.)
    --use-stderr   =  Don't merge stdout/stderr.
    --             = Pass remaining options to the native tool
```

But I didn't try it...